# How Would I Make an "ajax" Calendar Extender That Starts With The Current Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to set the start and end date of an `ajax` calendar extender control.

I want to make it so that my calendar starts from todays date.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <asp:Label ID="lblTravelStartDate" runat="server" Text="Travel Start Date" class="apply-page-label" ></asp:Label>              

    <div class="posRelative" id="Div3">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTravelFromDate" runat="server" onpaste="return false;" placeHolder="Travel Start Date" class="form-control" onclick="removeerror(this.id)" autopostback="true" . OnTextChanged="txtTravelFromDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="cmdTravelFromDate" ImageUrl="images/calander.png"  Height="25px" Width="25px" Style="position: absolute; top: 3px; right: 5px;"  OnClientClick="removeError('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTravelFromDate')" />

    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calTravelFromDate" runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" TargetControlID="txtTravelFromDate" PopupButtonID="cmdTravelFromDate"  CssClass="calender"> . </cc1:CalendarExtender>     
</div>
```

Comment: i want that my calendar start from current month..with previous dates disbled...

Answer (score 0):

The next time you should post your code if you don'w want to be down voted.
What you want is to set `YourAjaxCalendarID.StartDate = DateTime.Now()`from your codebehind `Page_Load()`

Comment: He did post his code but he didn't format it correctly so it wasn't displayed. This edit should have resolved that issue.

Comment: I just tested on my local machine and everything works as intended. Are you sure you are running the latest toolkit version?